# Python - Pillow ImageShow.show() isn't displaying images (Raspbian)

Tags: python, image, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library, raspbian

All I'm trying to do is display an image using Pillow on Raspberry Pi 3

First tried using this code:

```
from PIL import Image 
from PIL import ImageShow

imageA = Image.open('Moth.png')
ImageShow.show(imageA)
print("Done")
```

It didn't work, no error code, no nothing, it just skipped the code entirely

I digged a bit around and found out that maybe there could be an issue with the image displayer, so I tried adding it in like this:

```
from PIL import Image 
from PIL import ImageShow

imageA = Image.open('Moth.png')
ImageShow.show(imageA,title=None,command='GPicView')
print("Done")
```

It didn't work either, I also tried installing fim and using

`ImageShow.show(imageA,title=None,command='fim')`

like one of the answers on this site suggested, but that didn't work either

I made sure that fim has been installed correctly, so there must be something wrong with the code, but I can't understand what, maybe I didn't import ImageShow the right way?

I also tried using

```
imageA.show(command='fim')
```

But it yields the same results

I'm new to coding with Python (and in general), so maybe I'm just doing something stupid without realizing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I think newer versions of PIL/Pillow use the `xdg-open` command to display images. Internally, PIL/Pillow saves your in-memory image as a PNG file on disk and calls the OS's viewer to view that on-disk PNG. So, I presume there must be a way to set the default viewer for MIME-type *"image/png"* to be the viewer of your choice, but as a Mac user, I am unsure how you would do that - I guess it is possible with the `xdg-mime` command.

**Original Answer**

I think PIL/Pillow works something like this when displaying on Unix/Linux systems:

- it expects and hopes to find `display` which is part of **ImageMagick**
- it will use `eog` *"Eye of Gnome"* if it finds it
- it will fall back to `xv`

So, there are a number of possibilities depending on your skill-set, patience, disk-space, desire to use a specific viewer. I don't know those parameters, so here are some possibilities:

**Option:** Install **ImageMagick** with:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

**Option:** Install **eog** with:

```
sudo apt install eog
```

**Option:** Install **xv** - I don't have the exact command to hand

**Option:** Install **feh** or some other viewer and symlink it to `display` so PIL/Pillow thinks it is using **ImageMagick** `display`

```
sudo apt install feh
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/feh /usr/bin/display
```

---

Another option might be to create a custom viewer as a derived class from PIL's `UnixViewer` that places itself at the top of the list of viewers so it is used first.

So, create a file called `"CustomViewer.py"` that looks like this - mine uses the `feh` viewer but you can use any application you like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import shutil
import sys

from PIL import Image, ImageShow

class CustomViewer(ImageShow.UnixViewer):
   format = "PNG"
   options = {"compress_level": 1}

   def get_command_ex(self, file, **options):
      command = executable = "feh"
      return command, executable

if shutil.which("feh"):
   print(f'Registering custom viewer for PIL')
   ImageShow.register(CustomViewer, order=-1) # Insert as primary viewer
```

Then, in your regular Python code where you want to use your custom viewer, just add:

```
import CustomViewer
```

and it will output a message saying it is loaded and any subsequent calls to `show()` will use your custom viewer.

Comment: Hi! Both the gnome viewer and using your code to trick pillow worked

(I used the default image viewer GPicView instead of feh)

Would you happen to know a way to change the name on the display window too? Right now it shows the name of the temp image

Thank you very much regardless of that ^-^

Comment: I don't use `GPicView` so I am not the best person to ask. I looked at the manual page and help for `GPicView` and there doesn't appear to be any way to set the title in the display. I notice though that if I have some random image, e.g. `abc123.png` and I create a symbolic link to it with `ln -s abc123.png FreddyFrog.png` I can then use `GPicView FreddyFrog.png` and it will actually show `abc123.png` but with the title `FreddyFrog.png` so you  should be able to adapt that concept if you are that keen on `GPicView`.

Comment: Thanks! I've not been able to make it work, but I found out that if I open normally the image file I need to be named it will stay named, and it won't be closed when using `os.system("pkill display")` (which is the command I use to close all the images opened by Pillow) because it is opened with the normal GPicView, which works for my project!