# Python PIL .show() let me see the image ~20/30 secs, no more

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```py
image = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(X,Y), color=(255,255,255))
image.show()
```

It show the image but for 20/30 secs. Maybe a link to temporary files. Have I to change the tempt file deletion ?

I am on Linux mint.

Comment: This needs significantly more details to become answerable.

Comment: @possum I understand, but I litterally have nothing else. I juste use Show in IDLE or terminal and is show's but for few seconds. I have no other ideas other than maybe a link with the tempt files

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues with matplotlib so I suppose the problem has to do with a missing rendering part.

I read on the [PIL documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html):

> The standard version of show() is not very efficient, since it saves the image to a temporary file and calls a utility to display the image. If you don’t have an appropriate utility installed, it won’t even work. When it does work though, it is very handy for debugging and tests.

I also found this stackoverflow answer which may help with your issue:
[Python - Pillow ImageShow.show() isn't displaying images (Raspbian)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71170960/python-pillow-imageshow-show-isnt-displaying-images-raspbian)

I tried running it on my Linux Penguin but I'd get the error:

> No applications found for mimetype: image/png

So I installed ImageMagick:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

After this it worked for me but as I'm on Linux Penguin I'm not sure I may be of much more help for your platform to download an adapted image viewer. Maybe add more details since I'm not sure if I'm helping with this information. You could try to display the image with another module such as matplotlib and see how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunatly id didn't worked. But thanks, a lot, now I know where to look to fix this anoying problem.

Comment: Didn't expected someone will have this issue, thx !

Comment: Not really an answer but StackOverflow won't let me comment so good luck with my advice and hope it is the actual issue.

Comment: I finded thank's to you're links. I have to overwrite the Image viewer with "ImageShow.register(ImageShow.XDGViewer(), 0)". There is multiple options. XDGViewer this worked for me

Comment: So it is the issue. I installed thoses things, I just needed to overwrite to a Viewer that work better than the messy one

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```py
from PIL import ImageShow
ImageShow.register(ImageShow.XDGViewer(), 0)
```

Here : https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html
it's written that "*The standard version of show() is not very efficient, since it saves the image to a temporary file and calls a utility to display the image. If you don’t have an appropriate utility installed, it won’t even work. When it does work though, it is very handy for debugging and tests.*"

So I go to : https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.show

"*This method calls PIL.ImageShow.show() internally. You can use PIL.ImageShow.register() to override its default behaviour.*"

***And Here is the answere :***

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageShow.html#PIL.ImageShow.register

```py
from PIL import ImageShow
ImageShow.register(MyViewer())  # MyViewer will be used as a last resort
ImageShow.register(MySecondViewer(), 0)  # MySecondViewer will be prioritised
ImageShow.register(ImageShow.XVViewer(), 0)  # XVViewer will be prioritised
```

This to install libs if some are missing : [Python - Pillow ImageShow.show() isn't displaying images (Raspbian)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71170960/python-pillow-imageshow-show-isnt-displaying-images-raspbian)

To get the list of aviable options go to https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/ImageShow.html#register  or simply   `dir(ImageShow)` or just list them throught Idle posibility to list elements of a Class/File with the TAB key